# How to log unhandled exceptions in a vb.net class library project?

Tags: vb.net, logging, dll, class-library, exception-logging

I'm creating an add-in for Solidworks EPDM ([example from API help](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/epdmapi/DotNetAddIns.htm?id=c166025542774158b22184d5c44461e0#Pg0)).  This is a class library (.dll) project which is added to EPDM and allows some custom functions to be added to the program.

I want to add logging for unhandled errors so that when an exception is caused by my add-in (as opposed to by the Solidworks EPDM program itself) I can be notified of it and try to fix it.

I'm quite new to all of this (and by all of this I mean VB.NET as a language, programming anything other than macros in VBA, structured exception handling, error logging, etc) and I'm trying to follow [MSDN How To:  Log Exceptions in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9shkfdd(v=vs.120).aspx) but the instructions for logging unhanlded exceptions don't seem applicable to class library projects.

Specifically, I don't know how to get past step 3:

> **To log an unhandled exception**
>   1. Have a project selected in **Solution Explorer**. On the **Project** menu, choose **Properties**.
>   2. Click the **Application** tab.
>   3. Click the **View Application Events** button to open the Code Editor.
>   This opens the ApplicationEvents.vb file.

The `View Application Events` button is greyed out for class library projects.

[image]

So, is there another way to add logging for unhandled exceptions in class library projects? Or, another way to access the `ApplicationEvents.vb` file for class library objects?  I've tried searching for either, and have yet to find a solution that would allow me to log *unhandled* exceptions.

Comment: There are no unhandled exceptions in this scenario, the host program will get them.  It will surely display *something* but rarely good enough to help you diagnose the failure.  Put a Try/Catch in your DoCmd() method, don't forget to Throw it again so the host knows it went wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant - so you're recommending a try catch with a generic `catch ex as exception`, log it and re-throw it?

Comment: The "best" practice should be to make your code aware of *any* exception that could happen within it; either to handle it inside your add-in if it can/should, or to document it so the calling code can handle it if not. Having a global `try - catch` can help during developing and testing phases, but not for real scenarios; once you get all exceptions that can happen, you should get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic example but wrap your code with Try/Catch in the only two interface methods (host "callbacks") that `IEdmAddIn5` defines and which your add-in class must implement.

```
Public Sub GetAddInInfo(ByRef poInfo As EdmAddInInfo, ByVal poVault As IEdmVault5, ByVal poCmdMgr As IEdmCmdMgr5) Implements IEdmAddIn5.GetAddInInfo
    Try
       ...
    Catch ex As Exception
       ' Handle exception...
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub OnCmd(ByRef poCmd As EdmCmd, ByRef ppoData As System.Array) Implements IEdmAddIn5.OnCmd
    Try
       ...
    Catch ex As Exception
       ' Handle exception...
    End Try
End Sub
```

I would ordinarily agree with @Hans Passant about re-throwing the exception but I generally have found that to be problematic with an EPDM add-ins as it can cause the COM host to crash.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, although I am re-throwing any exceptions that I don't know how to handle.  I figure I would rather crash EPDM then put it into an unknown state.

Comment: IMO, I would just handle any exception. Also, remember that EPDM will throw COMExceptions by design for certain API methods if/when a call fails for certain seemingly benign reasons so watch for those gotchas in the documentation. In such cases usually wrapping the method call with an additional 'try/catch(COMException ex)...' is merited so that you can handle the expected HRESULT (the value correlates to an error message EPDM would otherwise show like "File format boy recognized.")

Comment: So where I'm at now is basically logging and swallowing anything non-fatal and unexpected. But exceptions like  `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException`, etc. I use `Throw()` to push back to EPDM as those are pretty much assuredly fatal ;)